# How to measure and record app startup time on App Center?

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-app-center

I am currently developing a Xamarin.Android app and I want not only to build the app on each commit, but also record the startup time (idea: if startup time increases, it is easy to identify due to which change).

Is that possible using App Center? Maybe using App Center's *launch test* functionality in combination with Application Insights? I know that Logcat displays the startup time (time between launching the process and finishing drawing the corresponding activity), could that maybe be extracted using Application Insights?

Comment: about Application Insights, I just search this sample:https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Xamarin, you can take a look, may be it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What I have been doing is, with a Stopwatch instance I measure each method I'm calling, put them in a dictionary and then using the TrackEvent method I send all the information together. It may not tell you the time it takes to render but it will give you a good idea of what method is taking the longest to execute.

You would have something like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var totalTime = 0L;
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopWatch.Start();
        UserDialogs.Init(() => this);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        totalTime += stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        dictionary.Add("UserDialogs.Init(() => this); (ms)", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

        stopWatch.Restart();
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        totalTime += stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        dictionary.Add("global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState); (ms)", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

        stopWatch.Restart();
        LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer()));
        stopWatch.Stop();
        totalTime += stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        dictionary.Add("LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer())) (ms)", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

        dictionary.Add("Total Startup Time", totalTime.ToString());
        Analytics.TrackEvent("Load completed", dictionary);
    }
```

Comment: thanks! can you elaborate on your code? I don't quite understand it. My understanding was when OnCreate is called, most stuff is already done. But you call things like Forms.Init and new App. I am using Xamarin.Android, not Xamarin.Forms, maybe that explains the difference? I don't know anything about Xamarin.Forms yet, so I can't judge that ;-)